# How to get response of chatterbot in image/hyperlink format?

Tags: python, django, chatterbot

Not able to get response of ChatterBot as image/hyper link.

I tried to place html image tag in my training data set i.e., .

**Training data set:**

image_response_data_set.yml

```
categories:
- myown
conversations:
- - can you show me smiley image?
  - <img src="example.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

As my  tag is considering as a string, it won't show me as image.

Can any one help me, how can i train bot to give response as image?

Do I need to use any other format instead of `.yml`?

Is there any Logic Adapter for that?

**Note:** I'm doing this using `ChatterBot/examples/django_app` from github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite certain that the example has anything coded into it to make it render images.

If you change the code `$row.text(text);` to `$row.html(text);` in the file `examples/django_app/example_app/templates/app.html` you might see your image rendered as HTML instead of text.

Comment: how to load static files in `$row.html(text)`? It is not loading `static files` with  `$row.html(text)`. Can you please give an idea?

Comment: The Django documentation has a very good section on how to load static files:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/